# PHP and MySQL Select a Single Value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, user-accounts

I'd like to know how to select a single value from my MySQL table. The table includes columns `username` and `id` amongst others (`id` is auto-increment and `username` is unique). Given the username, I want to set a session variable `$_SESSION['myid']` equal to the value in the `id` column that corresponds to the given username. Here's the code that I've already tried:

```
session_start();
$name = $_GET["username"];
$sql = "SELECT 'id' FROM Users WHERE username='$name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$value = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$_SESSION['myid'] = $value;
```

So far I'm getting:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

Casting `$value` to type string does not fix the problem.

Comment: Just a reminder... The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: This has serious security problems. As @WesC points out, don't use the mysql_* functions. Also, you are wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. Don't use quotation in a field name or table name inside the query.
2. After fetching an object you need to access object attributes/properties (in your case id) by attributes/properties name.

One note: **please use mysqli_* or PDO since mysql_* deprecated.** Here it is using mysqli:

```
session_start();
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db_name');
$link->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
$name = $_GET["username"];
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username=? limit 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$value = $result->fetch_object();
$_SESSION['myid'] = $value->id;
```

*Bonus tips: Use limit 1 for this type of scenario, it will save execution time :)*

Comment: This worked in eliminating the error message, but printing `$_SESSION['myid']` to the screen now displays "id" rather than a specific int.

Comment: @user3055501 : try above code. I have changed in $sql line and provide your feedback. It should work :)

Comment: ...and never use raw user input in your query.

Answer (score 11):

The mysql_* functions are deprecated and unsafe. *The code in your question in vulnerable to [injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).* It is **highly** recommended that you use the PDO extension instead, like so:

```
session_start();

$query = "SELECT 'id' FROM Users WHERE username = :name LIMIT 1";
$statement = $PDO->prepare($query);
$params = array(
    'name' => $_GET["username"]
);
$statement->execute($params);
$user_data = $statement->fetch();

$_SESSION['myid'] = $user_data['id'];
```

Where `$PDO` is your PDO object variable. See https://www.php.net/pdo_mysql for more information about PHP and PDO.

### For extra help:

Here's a jumpstart on how to connect to your database using PDO:

```
$database_username = "YOUR_USERNAME";
$database_password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
$database_info = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME";
try
{
    $PDO = new PDO($database_info, $database_username, $database_password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // Handle error here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Wes. I'll definitely look into PDO when I have more time.

Comment: From personal experience, I recommend you look into it sooner rather than later. The more code you write using the `mysql_*` functions, the more you'll find out that you'll be required to entirely rewrite. Plus, it's actually pretty convenient and more organized in other areas.

Comment: in case someone else sees this and panics, you can change to mysqli instead which is better. note the i at the end of mysql

Comment: Like @AndersM said - I also find mysqli easier to use/read than PDO, for simple queries. Note however that Wes is making a very important point: if any part of your query includes text that is not 100% under your control, then *use a prepared statement*. In mysqli, that is `prepare`, [manual discussion of prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_*` extension has been deprecated in 2013 and removed completely from PHP in 2018. You have two alternatives [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

#### PDO

The simpler option is PDO which has a neat helper function [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute([ $_GET["username"] ]);
$value = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

[Proper PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

#### MySQLi

You can do the same with MySQLi, but it is more complicated:

```
$stmt = $mysqliConn->prepare('SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username=?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET["username"]);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
$value = $data ? $data['id'] : null;
```

`fetch_assoc()` could return NULL if there are no rows returned from the DB, which is why I check with ternary if there was any data returned.

Since PHP 8.1 you can also use `fetch_column()`

```
$stmt->execute();
$value = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_column();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893254/get-id-from-mysql-database-and-load-data-based-on-it?noredirect=1#comment105915322_59893254  (it is surprisingly hard to find secure queries to close new questions with.)

Answer (score 3):

You do this by using `mysqli_fetch_field` method.

```
session_start();
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$name = $_GET["username"];
$sql = "SELECT 'id' FROM Users WHERE username='$name' limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if ($result !== false) {
    $value = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    $_SESSION['myid'] = $value;
}
```

Note: you can do that by using `mysql_fetch_field()` method as well, but it will be deprecated in php v5.5

Comment: mysqli_fetch_field "Returns an object which contains field definition information or FALSE if no field information is available." so this won't work as suggested by the answer. -1 because of this.

Comment: @GusstavvGil: I've corrected the code by making sure there is a valid $result, before the call to `mysqli_fetch_field`. I've also added the missing $link parameter.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve mysqli_fetch_field does not return the value. It returns the field definition, like name, table, flags. -1 because of this... http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php

Comment: This answer should not be used because it is insecure/unstable.

Comment: **Warning:** This answer is totally wrong. `mysqli_fetch_field()` returns metadata about a table column, not the value itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$value = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: "Try this" answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Even if you feel your solution is ultra-basic/self-explanatory, ALL answers should include some form of plain English supporting text.  Tell researchers how it works, why it works, how it is different from other answers, why you think it is a good idea, provide link(s) to documentation, etc.  Simply be generous when you answer with the intent to help people and role model good answer posting behaviour to others.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `mysql_fetch_object`, you get an object (of class stdClass) with all fields for the row inside of it.

Use `mysql_fetch_field` instead of `mysql_fetch_object`, that will give you the first field of the result set (`id` in your case). The docs are [here](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_field)

Comment: **Warning:** This answer is totally wrong. `mysql_fetch_field()` returns metadata about a table column, not the value itself.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite evident that there is only a single `id` corresponding to a single `username` because `username` is unique.

But the actual problem lies in the query itself-

```
$sql = "SELECT 'id' FROM Users WHERE username='$name'";
```

### O/P

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| id |
+----+
```

***i.e. `'id'` actually is treated as a string not as the `id` attribute.***

### Correct synatx:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM Users WHERE username='$name'";
```

i.e. use **grave accent**(`) instead of **single quote**(').

**or**

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username='$name'";
```

### Complete code

```
session_start();
$name = $_GET["username"];
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM Users WHERE username='$name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
$value = $row[0];
$_SESSION['myid'] = $value;
```

Comment: Needs a ; on the fifth line.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
session_start();
$name = $_GET["username"];
$sql = "SELECT 'id' FROM Users WHERE username='$name' LIMIT 1 ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
      $_SESSION['myid'] = $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.