# Getting specific column value / data from a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to put only the value of column `id` from table `existence`:

```php
$sql_query_existence = "SELECT * FROM existence ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$sql_test = $sql_query_existence['id'];
```

The second line is my idea, how do I do this right? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: "SELECT id FROM existence ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

Comment: Your idea is incorrect.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP and MySQL Select a Single Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878089/php-and-mysql-select-a-single-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to *get* the value of the `id` column? If so, use this query

```
SELECT id FROM existence ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

and if you want to *set* the value of the `id` column only, use either

```
INSERT INTO existence(id) VALUES (<Your ID>);
```

or

```
UPDATE existence SET id=<Your ID> WHERE ...;
```

---

This answer is SQL based since I don't know php, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20878134/7571171) will help you do the necessary php work involved.